# Diagonalizable operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ be a linear operator such that $\dim\textrm{ker}(T)=2$ and its characteristic polynomial is $p_T(t)=t^3(t+1)$. Is this operator diagonalizable?

With this hypothesis, I tried to find the minimal polynomial and see if this polynomial is product of linear factors, but I don't known if this is the correct way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Proposition.** The linear operator $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if its characteristic polynomial splits over the base field **and** if for all its eigenvalues, the algebraic multiplicity *i.e.* the multiplicity of the eigenvalue as a root of the characteristic polynomial, equals the geometric multiplicity *i.e.* the dimension of the associated eigenspace.

Here, the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is $3$ and its geometric multiplicity is $2$. Hence, $T$ is not diagonalizable.

You could also have proceeded by contradiction. If $T$ were diagonalizable, since its characteristic polynomial is $t^3(t+1)$, it would be similar to $\textrm{diag}(0,0,0,-1)$, which has a kernel of dimension $3$. This is a contradiction, since the dimension of the kernel is invariant through conjugation.